# How to split a line to a new line when specific condition meets in a csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

I have the below data in my csv file, I want to split each line to a new line when "05/16/2019" text is identified using c#.

Currently in my csv file data format is like below:

05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GbK,R0000001,1,05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1,05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1

I want to change like below:

05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1
05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1
05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1

I am new to c# programming, Can anyone please help me with the Code?

1st Step:  I am Uploading my csv file
2nd Step: I am trying to change my csv as above requirement
3rd Step: Exporting the modified csv to a new location

```
List<string> csvfiles = new List<string>();
private void btnimport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                csvfiles.Add(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
public void csvedit()
    {
        String path = @"C:\Users\Sunil\Videos\original\GSK.csv";
        Regex r = new Regex(@",(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})");   // looks for the comma just before the date
        var newStr = r.Replace(path, "\r\n");
    }
 private void btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        csvedit();
        string installedPath = "C:\\Users\\Sunil\\Videos\\changed";

        //Check whether folder path is exist
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(installedPath))
        {
            // If not create new folder
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(installedPath);
        }
        //Save pdf files in installedPath ??
        foreach (string sourceFileName in csvfiles)
        {
            string destinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(installedPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName));
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
            MessageBox.Show("File Exported Successfully");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Sunil, Can you provide us what you tried so far?

Comment: Your CVS file is invalid. Make sure quotation marks are matching.

Comment: There's no `"05/16/2019"` in this file. It looks like someone used the double quote as a *row separator*. You can use that in your code (which you haven't provided, so we can't help you) or in any library that reads CSV files (eg CsvHelper) to read data. Double quotes are the default *text qualifier* which probably means you'd have to configure the library to *not* check for text qualifiers

Comment: I'd suggest contacting whoever produced that file and ask them to *not* use double quotes as a line separator, because it's actually the *text* qualifier. [It violates the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2)

Comment: Actually, there are no double quotes, Just I want to split that to a new line when 05/16/2019 text is identified

Comment: @SunilEdupuganti are you sure that the original file doesnt contain `\n` instead of `\r\n` (and I guess that you are on windows). Can you try to open it with another editor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the current CSV format is available as string in your code, you can use the regular expressions for formatting the way you want. Try with this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@",(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})");   // looks for the comma just before the date
var newStr = r.Replace(str, "\r\n");         // here 'str' is the input string which contains unformatted csv file content.
```

For your requirement, you need to modify the `csvedit()` as follows:

```
public void csvedit()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Sunil\Videos\original\GSK.csv";
    string csvContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    Regex r = new Regex(@"("",""(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))");  // looks for the 'double quotes - comma - double quotes' pattern just before the date
    var newStr = r.Replace(csvContent, "\n").Trim("\"".ToArray());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, newStr);    //this will overwrite the text present in existing file.
}
```

Comment: I have done what you have said, but it didn't work. I have updated my code as well. Could you please look into it and correct me if I do any mistakes.

Comment: added the code to read from csv file, processing it as per the requirement and writing it back to the same file. You may try it.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. I have tested the regular expression in https://regex101.com/ It doesn't identify the comma before the date.

Comment: The regular expression is correct. I had tested it in my demo code. And I tried it in the link which you have shared. It is working there also. Maybe you are not writing the regular expression correctly  in the textbox. Try this in that textbox: `(,(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))`

Comment: Sorry, Actually it was my mistake. In my CSV file before the date, there is a (") as well. It looks like below.
"05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,1,8,"05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,2,4","05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,GSK,R0000001,3                             

So, I changed my regular expression as (,"(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))
But when i use it in the code it is giving me the error. Could you please modify the regular expression according to the code level. Currently I am using like below
Regex r = new Regex(@"(,"(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})");

Comment: Use this:"(,(?=""[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))"

Comment: What error? Is the error in the regular expression?

Comment: Please check the below link for the error screenshot.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14EGi5lKVYoJKBwve-ySMN-0xjR1Z7ZGr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use like this: new Regex(@"(,(?=""[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))");

Comment: Thank you so much, It works. I want to delete the double quotes at the starting and the End. How can i do this?  Here is my Sentence in a csv file                                                                                                   

"05/16/2019,PAPER,190516-TRE-5419,R0000001,1,How likely are you to recommend this program to a colleague in the future,""Scale of 0-10, 0=No opinion, 1=Not at all likely, 10=Extremely likely."",8"

Comment: To delete the double quotes, u need to use this regular expression:
`new Regex(@"("",""(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))");`
 And you need to use `newStr.Trim("\"".ToArray());` after that. I have edited the answer. Please follow that.

Comment: It worked, but for the first sentence starting double quote is not removed, Actually there will be total of 7 sentences. At the starting and the ending of each sentence there is a double quote. Every double quote is removed except the first sentence starting position

Comment: please share the way u have implemented. The code which i have provided, works. I have tested in my demo solution

Comment: Please check the below link, I have shared you the csv file. I need to remove the double quotes for the first sentence and also I need to remove the two commas for the last question.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_8l6g_rloM49uZFJH2UO9U2jqJsleEz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking at your file, sorry to say but I cannot help you with this. If you look at the question, I have answered as per that way back and just with the intention to help you out, I provided solutions to your specific scenarios even after that. StackOverflow isnot meant for spoon feeding. You have enough leads and you ought to work over things by your own as well and if you think you don't have the knowledge to proceed on that, then you should look to first gather it.